Installing cuda on Docker on Ubuntu
I'm trying to use CUDA and tensorflow on Docker on Ubuntu.
My machine has a GPU (GeForce GTX 1070) and of course I'd like to use it through Docker.
Ubuntu(Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) was newly installed the other day and I've never used Docker nor CUDA since I installed Ubuntu.
What I did is listed below.
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
$ sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
$ sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc

$ sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc

$ echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc]\
https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME") stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

$ sudo docker run hello-world
...
Hello from Docker!

So, Docker works.
$ curl https://get.docker.com | sh \
  && sudo systemctl --now enable docker

$ distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) \
      && curl -fsSL https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | sudo gpg --    dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg \
      && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/$distribution/libnvidia-    container.list | \
            sed 's#deb https://#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://#g' | \
            sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit

$ sudo sed -i -e '/experimental/ s/^#//g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list
$ sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo nvidia-ctk runtime configure --runtime=docker
INFO[0000] Config file does not exist; using empty config 
INFO[0000] Wrote updated config to /etc/docker/daemon.json 
INFO[0000] It is recommended that docker daemon be restarted. 

$ sudo systemctl restart docker
$ sudo docker image ls
REPOSITORY    TAG                       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
nvidia/cuda   11.6.2-base-ubuntu20.04   2098e65daccd   5 months ago    154MB
hello-world   latest                    d2c94e258dcb   11 months ago   13.3kB

At this point, I think I can create a container but actually it doesn't work.
$ sudo docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.6.2-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi
...
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown.

Could anyone point out what is wrong with me and what I should do?

Have you installed the propriatary Nvidia drivers on the system? I.e. nvidia-smi works outside a container?

Thanks, paleonix. Not yet. Should I install them onto the host, not onto the container?

While it is nowadays possible to run the driver in a container as well, that is an advanced feature. Normally the driver is installed on the host because it works at the kernel level and the kernel is shared between containers.

Thanks, paleonix. I installed an Nvidia driver and now everything works perfectly.
